# Android Studio start fail after installing plugins

Tags: android-studio, plugins

I installed 2 plugins as color schemes and restarted the application but I get start failure message how to fix this? First plugin is [material theme ui](https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains) and the other is the first one in the list when you search for material theme ui in the repositories can't remember it's name

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.FileTypeManager'
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:212)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:380)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.FileTypeManager'
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:257)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:501)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:106)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:437)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:444)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:90)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:396)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:382)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:205)
... 16 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.intellij.util.PlatformIcons
at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.UserFileType.<init>(UserFileType.java:28)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.AbstractFileType.<init>(AbstractFileType.java:58)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.loadFileType(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:1383)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.initStandardFileTypes(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:317)
at com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.impl.FileTypeManagerImpl.<init>(FileTypeManagerImpl.java:255)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:459)
... 28 more
```